# @Profile vs @ConditionalOnProperty

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, profiling

Recently I was asked to create a new `profile` to (de)activate a feature. I have two situations where I have to make changes:

```
class A {

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        SecurityConfigurer ldapConfigurer = securityFactory.ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer();
        ldapConfigurer.configure(auth);
        SecurityConfigurer offlineConfigurer = securityFactory.offlineAuthenticationProviderConfigurer();
        offlineConfigurer.configure(auth);
    }

}
```

In the class above, if the profile is active, the last two lines don't have to be executed. I extended the class and assign it the new profile `@Profile("notOffline")` and in the original class I put `@Profile("!notOffline")`.

```
class A {

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        SecurityConfigurer ldapConfigurer = securityFactory.ldapAuthenticationProviderConfigurer();
        ldapConfigurer.configure(auth);
        SecurityConfigurer offlineConfigurer = securityFactory.offlineAuthenticationProviderConfigurer();
        offlineConfigurer.configure(auth);
    }

}

    class B extends A {
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            super();
            SecurityConfigurer offlineConfigurer = securityFactory.offlineAuthenticationProviderConfigurer();
            offlineConfigurer.configure(auth);
        }

    }
```

The second place I have to refactor is something like this:

```
class C {

public Something foo() {
     code();
     code();
     code();
     thisLineHasNotToBeExecuted();
     code();
     code();
     return something;
    }

}
```

The line that has not to be executed depends on variables that the rest of the method use, and it's not what is returning. The approach I made before is not the happy one for this case (and there are two methods that are invoking this method that has not to be executed).

After some time I realized that a better approach would be to add a property to the last class which is annotated with `@Value` and pass the argument to the tomcat on the startup. This way I could have an `if` inside `thisLineHasNotToBeExecuted()` and I could use `@ConditionalOnProperty` on `class A` and its child.

Is my approach correct?

Some more info: what I'm (de)activating an failover authentication when we use ActiveDirectory and in the second class I'm preventing to save user information in the cache.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your use of profiles in the first case would be appropriate.

`@ConditionalOnProperty` is not the correct way to handle your second use case. It is normally to be used for startup configuration with Spring Boot Starter projects.

Your idea of using a property and adding an `if` condition to decide whether to execute `thisLineHasNotToBeExecuted();` is on the right track. If the execution of that one line is dependent on the profile, then you can inject the active profile into the class and key off of that value. If you are using the spring boot config server, then be sure and add an `@RefreshScope`.